# swagger + JBoss 6.4 + Resteasy

Tags: java, maven, jboss, swagger

I need to install swagger on JBoss 6.4 using provided Resteasy implementation.

I've followed the installation instruction on [this link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X)

Therefore this is my configuration:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.5.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

When I deploy the application package on JBoss, I see the following error:

> ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig
>   ...

Any solution?

Comment: Check in you "war" if you find "swagger-jaxrs-1.5.0.jar"

Comment: Actually maven package in the war dependencies with scope compiled. But you can try put this jar in the Jboss shared lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved: Actually my webapp had more modules, so I had to declare jar dependency into another module instead of war.